Relation Variation inflation factor to standard error
I am reading  chapter 3 Linear regression, from the ISLP book.
Section 6. Collinearity is extremely confusing to me. First of all, it shows contours plot of RSS associated with possible estimation of $\beta_i$'s: if the two coefficients are highly correlated the contours run along a narrow valley that means hight $SE(\beta_i)$.
However I don't understand how the variability of RSS for given sample  can be related to the Standard error of $beta_i$'s over different samples.

Then it introduce the VIF(short for variation inflation factor)to be the ratio of variance of $\beta_j$ when fitting the full model over variance of $\beta_j$ when fit alone.
Also it introduce a formula to calculate VIF  to be:
$$\text{VIF}(\hat{\beta}_j) = \frac{1}{1 - R^2_{X_j | X_{-j}}}$$
That is just a formula based on R2 of how good we can fit $x_j$ based on rest of predictors. I don't understand how this formula is equal to ration of variance if $\beta_j$ when fitting the whole model divided by variance of $\beta_j$ when fit alone. Cause these two things are completely separate to me and I can't connect the dots.
I would appreciate any intuitive explanation for making sense of these concepts.
PS: I actually duplicated a column of data and result shows keeping both, has lower se than training with only one of them


Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/149442/7071.
